# Real-time audio processing to "translate" frequencies

Tags: android, real-time, javasound, android-audiorecord, frequency-analysis

I would like to know if there is a way to do **real-time audio processing** in **Android**, to translate the listening of the audible band to various ultrasound band centered for example on 20, or 40 or 60 kHz.

I've already found a way to display a real-time spectrogram based on the use of `AudioRecord`.

But this seems to be more "specific", so I don't know what should be the good approach, or if this is feasable...

**Edit:**

I've asked my client to give me more details about this requirement.

He explained me that he wants the app allowing users to

1. **play** the **sound** in live on the phone speaker
2. **"transpose" a selected frequency range to the hearable frequency range** (0 - 20 kHz) and play the "transposed" sound  on the phone speaker :

   - 20 - 40 kHz => 0 - 20 kHz
   - 40 - 60 kHz => 0 - 20 kHz
   - 60 - 80 kHz => 0 - 20 kHz

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by translate?

Comment: It's hard to explain, but the main goal  is to make the "ultrasounds" audible to the human ear, by adjusting the frequency ranges, through a slider or another control.

Comment: It’s only possible if you have hardware that can actually capture ultrasound. By default none really are

Comment: What I mean by "ultrasound" it's more the sounds that aren't audible cause they are in a "too higher" frequency. The app will use a microphone, but not a dedicated device to track ultrasounds.

Comment: And unless you have hardware that can capture those frequencies you can’t. Microphones have their frequency limits and so do ADCs so they have to go high enough. For 60kHz you’d need at least 120kHz sampling frequency, preferably even more to actually capture it properly

Comment: What you are talking about is called ***transposing*** a frequency (i.e.: multiply or divide it by 2 to get the higher or lower octave, respectively). And, as @SamiKuhmonen pointed out, you need a device capable of capturing those higher frequencies (at a *sampling rate which is usually the double of the highest frequency*). I highly doubt that a common phone or table has such features.

Comment: Thanks for your comments: I've added some details after having contacted my client. Could you confirm me that should be hard to achieve?

Comment: Unless you don't have an ultrasonic transducer, yes. You would probably need some hardware device inbetween. But then an Android device would be useless, since you're already getting your result in hardware.